# Inserting multiline text in a csv field

Tags: text, csv, multiline, export-to-csv

I want to insert a multiline text data in a CSV field.

Ex:

```
var data = "\nanything\nin\nthis\nfield";
var fields = "\"Datafield1\",\"Datafield2:"+data+"\"\n";
```

When I save `fields` into a **csv** file and open it using MS Excel, I get to see only the first column. But when I open the file using a text editor I see:

> "Datafield1","Datafield2:
>   anything
>   in 
>   this
>   field"

I don't know whether I am going against **CSV** standards. Even if I am going against Please help me with a workaround.

Thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default MS Excel uses semicolon as a separator. use `;` and you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: Just use: `var fields = "\"Datafield1\";\"Datafield2:"+data+"\"\n";`

Comment: It's not working for me..
I tried manually in excel as ="'1';'1';'1'" and ="1;1;1".. Both are not working. Please help

Comment: The RFC 4180 CSV standard defines the structure of a how a big blob of string that spans many lines, is to be created. However one important gotcha is that when the next line begins with a whitespace character, many parsers consider it a different record.

Answer (score 4):

Here I place some text followed by the *NewLine* char followed by some more text and the 
whole string MUST be quoted into a field in a csv file.

Do not use a CR since EXCEL will place it in the next cell.

> ""2" + NL + "DATE""

When you invoke EXCEL, you will see this. You may have to auto size the height to see the entire cell.

2

DATE

Here's the code in Basic

```
CHR$(34,"2", 10,"DATE", 34)
```